# Tensorflow Serving crashes with multiple requests simultaneously

Tags: tensorflow-serving

Tensorflow Serving crashes with multiple requests simultaneously, the error message is:

```
*** Error in `tensorflow_model_server': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007ff474c18cc0 ***
```

I have tried batching, it doesn't work out.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libtcmalloc-minimal4
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4"
```

got different error with the same issue.

```
*** Error in `tensorflow_model_server': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x00007f2ee8fa7920 ***
```

Is there any easy way to solve this without using kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't enough information here to debug the issue. If it's a problem with your model, then you'll likely get this issue eventually no matter how you serve it.

Comment: If running with requests sequentially, there is no crash. So it is not a problem for the model.